# What is the difference between gtk builder file and libglade file when using Glade designer?

Tags: python, linux, gtk, glade

I'm using glade interface designer for developing a simple application. I was actually following a tutorial which was based on libglade format. But I want to use the gtkbuilder format. So I switched to the gtkbuilder format. But I just want to know what is the exact difference  between libglade format and gtkbuilder format.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Libglade was a separate library. It since has been deprecated, and the functionnalities have been integrated in GTK, which uses the GTK builder format which is a bit different. Both formats allow almost the same things, but the GtkBuilder one is prefered.